# Handling two user groups in front end Joomla 2.5

Tags: user, menu-item, login, user-groups

I'm maintaining two user groups in front end. They are customer and retailer. There are two menu items for them to login. That means two login sections. Therefore there are two menu items are assigned to same view - login. 
If there is an error occurred when login to system it redirect first menu item which is assigned to view - login. That means retailer section.

**Menu items**

- Retailer login - 106
- Customer login - 107

It always redirects to retailer login. This happens when we enable Search engine friendly urls only. I want to redirect them specific logins when error occurred.

Is there any solution for handling this kind situation please?

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want to control re-direct for specific user groups? If so, you may want to check out http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/12395 or http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/15257

Comment: Actually I have overrided user controller and check for user group in login task. According to user group, I need to redirect to specific login if there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments say, try the [Login Redirect Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect), but I had the same scenario, and opted to use a plugin called [Nomad](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect/18772).  What I liked about it (though you may not) is that it doesn't use the typical redirect that most of the similar plugins use, but instead dynamically *changes* their home page, based on the User Group.  The net effect is that visitors have the normal home page, but once a Customer or Retailer logs in, any link to "Home" is now changed to the page of your choosing.

Comment: Actually my scenario is different. I think I don't explain it well. I'm maintaining two login screens in front end. They are for customers and retailers. I restrict user login for different user groups in user controller(overrrided). But if there any error or redirection happens it goes to retailer login screen. Not for current user group's login screen. I think joomla uses first menu assignment which retailer login menu assignment.